# Excel spreadsheet cannot be published to sp 2010 list

Tags: list

I receive a "Cannot connect to server at this time. Your list cannot be published" error message when you import an Excel spreadsheet to use as a basis for a new list in Windows SharePoint Services

Answer (score 1):

I've encounterred that same error in 2 situations:

1. Either you Web Application is using Anonymous authentication - in
   which Excel is not able to rely on the authenticated user
2. You do not have a Site Collection created in the root of the Web Application. Also you should maybe try to run the import on the Top-Level site at first.

Comment: How can I know what kind of authentication my web application is using?

Answer (score 0):

Add the sharepoint root URL (e.g. https://sp.yourcompany.com) as trusted site in IE.

Comment: In my case the root URL was already added to the list of trusted sites. And yet it doesn't work.